# OpenVPN sets wrong metric on TAP interface

Tags: openvpn, route, windows-8.1, ubuntu-20.04

OpenVPN client: 3.2.1(1180) (Windows 8.1 x64)

```
TAP1 v9 Windows - metric manually set to 1000, just in case
Realtek RTL8192CU Wireless LAN 802.11n - main network card, metric manually set to 10
```

OpenVPN server: 2.4.7 (Ubuntu 20.04)
in `/etc/openvpn/server/server.conf`:

```
push "route-metric 1000"
```

After connecting to the server, the client sets TAP1's metric to 1 and that routes all traffic through the VPN which bottlenecks the server's connection. Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Yep, switched to WireGuard. It just works

Comment: Well this is basically not a solution, but a complete change :D

Comment: Exactly, sometimes a simple change is the solution

Comment: I read that push-metric will make Windows add the number you push to the metric, not setting it. That is to say, the available solution is apparently to set it manually on client's side. At least I have not found any thing else yet.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem and preferred to change the client instead to write a script for that

Comment: Does WireGuard work with OpenVPN server or should I setup a new server for it?

Comment: To be honest never tried that, but probably this won't be a problem for you to setup a Vbox machine with Windows or some Linux distro and test it